# How client application uses the scopes and resources extracted from access token to restrict the access of API - identityserver4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

I can see many links describing how to use identityserver4.

Host application:
Configuring clients with [clientId, secret, APIScopes, APIResources, IdentityResources]
Passing clients details to identityserver4

Client Application:
Passing client id to the endpoint to get access token and refresh token that contains scopes and resources of the defined clients. using that scope and resources we can restrict the access of the API's.

But I am still wondering how the client application will use the API scopes to restrict the access of the Application is there any sample how to utilize the scopes to restrict the application access?

And also approach for maintaining roles in identitserver4

I don't find any links describing how to use the client part after getting access token, please share me any reference that can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a API (AddJwtBearer), you do two things, authentication and authorization.

In the authorization stage, you check the claims (the scopes is part of the claims) found in the access token.

Can do the authorization check using the role or policy based approach.

A sample policy can look like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {

        options.AddPolicy("ViewReports", policy =>
                          policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                .RequireRole("Finance")
                                .RequireRole("Management")
                          );                  
    });
```

then you can decorate your controllers with this attribute:

```
[Authorize("ViewReports")]
public class SecretController : Controller
{
}
```

From a consumer (API) point of view, the scopes are just like all the other claims. they are not treated differently.

Answer (score 0):

When using identityserver4, client needs to configure the ClientId and the authority address, this server need to configure the allowed scope corresponding to clientid.

```
      services.AddAuthentication(config=>
        {
            config.DefaultScheme = "cookie";
            config.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
            .AddCookie("cookie")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", config=>
            {
                config.Authority = "url";
                config.ClientId = "client_id";
                config.ClientSecret = "client_secret";
                config.SaveTokens = true;
                config.ResponseType = "code";
            });
```

The Identityserver will authorize some functions according to the ClientId.

```
         new Client
            {
                ClientId="client_id",
                ClientSecrets=
                {
                    new Secret("client_secret".ToSha256())
                },
                AllowedGrantTypes=GrantTypes.Code,
                RedirectUris={ "https://localhost:[port]/signin-oidc"},
                AllowedScopes={ "apione", "apitwo", 
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    //...
                },
                RequireConsent=false
            }
```

In apione, you still need to configure the audience.

```
     services.AddAuthentication("jwtauth")
            .AddJwtBearer("jwtauth",config=>
            {
                config.Authority = "identityserver url";
                config.Audience = "apione";
                config.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

            });
```

Every user has their own role, so you can add the claims after the user logs in on the server. In addition, the project api can configure the AddAuthorization as Tore Nestenius says.